# How to insert and edit data gird row and save it into database without using any framework in sqlite using wpf and C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, datagrid, wpf-controls

I want to insert data into new rows and edit existing rows of data grid in db table.I have set in datagrid `CanUserAddRows="True"` in xaml .Here is my sqlite code for connecting with datagrid:

```
SQLiteCommand comm = new SQLiteCommand("update Security_details  set id=@id,Code=@Code,Description=@Description,Rate=@Rate,Qty=@Qty,Amount=@Amount,Remarks=@Remarks where id=@id", sqlitecon);
comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Tell me the set of commands for above query for inserting and updating data into data grid rows ?

I am first time coding in wpf using data grid .I search it on google the material i found is using entity frame work ..please help

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to use from BulkInsert. There Are some tricks to use from BulkInsert in SQLlite. There are many helps for single_row insertion that you can find with a search through google.

Here is a good link for your question (For Bulk Insert In Sqlite):

[https://www.jokecamp.com/blog/make-your-sqlite-bulk-inserts-very-fast-in-c/][1]

I hope it help.